# Creating thumbnails of div content

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, charts, thumbnails

I have very complex chart representation using svg (using [d3.js](http://d3js.org) library). Is it possible using javascript to create thumbnails of those area and display it somewhere on the page?

I have found jquery [nailthumb](http://www.garralab.com/nailthumb.php) plugin. But it needs image and it does not work exactly as I want.

Please let me know if it is even possible with javascript.

Comment: please share your code on jsfiddle

Comment: [this may work](http://grabz.it/)